# C: Check least significant and most significant byte for a 0 or 1

Tags: c

I am trying to check the least and most significant byte of an int separately.

I want to check if any bit in the least significant byte is one. I want to return 1 if true and 0 if false.
My attempt:

```
int lsb_one(int x) {
  return ( (x & 0xffff) != 0 );
}
```

I want to check if any bit in the most significant byte is zero. I want to return 1 if true and 0 if false.
My attempt:

```
int msb_zero(int x) {
  return ( (~(x & 0x0000ffff)) != 0 );
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Well just remember that one byte is two hex digits. 0xFF is a byte, not 0xFFFF.

Comment: *Any pointers?* Oblig: http://xkcd.com/138/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
int lsb_one(int x) {
    return ((x & 0xff) != 0 );
}

int msb_zero(int x) {
    return ((x & 0xff000000) != 0xff000000);
}
```

Note that the second version is platform dependent, assuming that int is a 32-bit value.

Comment: oh duh, only 2 hex digits. On msb_zero can you `return ( (~(x & 0x000000ff)) != 0 );` and still work?

Comment: Nope, I can't because I still need to check just the msb's

Comment: Also, if you compare to zero like that, that only tells you if all MSBs are zero or 1. It doesn't tell you if just one bit is zero, as your question said you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have already pointed out, your mask should be `0xff` instead of `0xffff` since a byte is usually 8 bits. To keep the `msb_zero` function implementation independent, use `CHAR_BIT` and `sizeof()` as follows:

```
#include <limits.h>

int msb_zero(int x) {
  return (x & (0xff << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - CHAR_BIT))) != 0;
}
```

The `CHAR_BIT` in `limits.h` provides you the number of bits is a char/byte.

**Edit** For completeness, the `lsb_one` function:

```
int lsb_one(int x) {
    return ((x & 0xff) != 0 );
}
```